# Select Criteria based on previous 5 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Name: INCLog

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCx2j.jpg)

```
UID Incident Number Modified Date   Modified By
1   INC000011193511 2/18/2018 12:04 zuck
1   INC000011193511 2/19/2018 1:42  shei
1   INC000011193511 3/14/2018 5:08  byrr
1   INC000011193511 3/17/2018 5:08  byrr
2   INC000011193513 1/23/2018 2:58  r070
2   INC000011193513 1/27/2018 9:27  r070
2   INC000011193513 2/21/2018 5:42  gont
2   INC000011193513 3/16/2018 6:06  r070
3   INC000011193514 2/1/2018 6:07   shei
3   INC000011193514 2/13/2018 6:07  r070
4   INC000011193515 2/20/2018 21:05 moha
4   INC000011193515 2/21/2018 8:05  moha
4   INC000011193515 3/15/2018 18:34 doss
```

How do I use Select statement to return incident numbers modified in last 5 days?
For an instance; INC000011193511 was last modified on 3/17/2018, the query should return the entire log of the same ticket

```
1   INC000011193511 2/18/2018 12:04 zuck
1   INC000011193511 2/19/2018 1:42  shei
1   INC000011193511 3/14/2018 5:08  byrr
1   INC000011193511 3/17/2018 5:08  byrr
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Last 5 days of what?   Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find last modified date for each incident with max window function. Then compare with current date. Your query should be something like:

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        *, mDate = max([modified date]) over (partition by [Incident Number])
    from
        myTable
) t
where
    mDate >= dateadd(dd, -5, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Uzi. Let me quickly try this

Comment: Before anyone else writes another incomplete answer; please actually read *this **complete** answer*...

Comment: Uzi, you are the best!! Your solution worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Praveen Works like a charm? That query does not produce the posted desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just last 5day transactions for specific transactions then you can use following query.

```
SELECT * FROM INCLog where IncedentNumber ='INC000011193511' AND ModifiedDate = DATEADD(DAY, - 5,GETDATE () )
```

Comment: `For an instance; INC000011193511 was last modified on 3/17/2018, the query should return the` ***`entire`*** `log of the same ticket`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this as:

```
SELECT Incident_Number, MAX(Modified_Date) maxDate
FROM TempTabel
GROUP BY Incident_Number
HAVING MAX(Modified_Date)) > = dateadd(dd, -5, getdate())
```

Thank You!

Comment: `For an instance; INC000011193511 was last modified on 3/17/2018, the query should return the` ***`entire`*** `log of the same ticket`  Your answer doesn't return any log records, at present.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you could use `group by` clause to find the max date of each Incident number and compare it with last 5 days

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT Incident, MAX([Modified Date]) Mdate FROM table
   WHERE Incident = t.Incident
   GROUP BY Incident) c
WHERE c.Mdate >= DATEADD(DD, -5 , getdate())
```